# Query latest record from a list of given data

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a requirement to query the latest record for a list of data. Here's my sample table (primary key omitted)

```
col1| createtime
d1  | 2013-01-31 22:04:15
d1  | 2014-01-31 22:04:15
d1  | 2015-01-31 22:04:15
d2  | 2013-01-31 22:04:15
d2  | 2014-01-31 22:04:15
d2  | 2014-02-31 22:04:15
d2  | 2015-01-31 22:04:15
d3  | 2013-01-31 22:04:15
d3  | 2014-01-31 22:04:15
d3  | 2014-01-31 22:04:15
d3  | 2015-01-31 22:04:15
d4  | 2013-01-31 22:04:15
d4  | 2014-01-31 22:04:15
d4  | 2015-01-31 22:04:15
```

A list of data of col1 are given. For example, the list of data given is [d3, d4]. The result of my query should be the rows

```
[(d3 2015-01-31 22:04:15),    (d4 2015-01-31 22:04:15)]
```

because the latest record for d3 is `2015-01-31 22:04:15` and the latest record for d4 is `2015-01-31 22:04:15`

Is this possible without using sql procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only two columns, just use `group by`:

```
select t.col1, max(t.createtime)
from table t
where t.col1 in ('d3', 'd4')
group by t.col1;
```

If you have more than two columns, I think the following will work:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.col1 in ('d3', 'd4') and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col1 and
                        t2.createtime > t.createtime
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a table expression

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY createtime DESC) AS Rnk
           ,col1
           ,createtime
    FROM tableName
)
SELECT col1, createtime FROM C WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following example can help you for your resolution:

```
select id, max(time_stamp)
  from (select 'd1' as id, '2013-01-31 22:04:15' as time_stamp from dual
        union all
        select 'd1', '2014-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd1', '2015-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd2', '2013-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd2', '2014-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd2', '2014-02-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd2', '2015-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd3', '2013-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd3', '2014-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd3', '2014-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd3', '2015-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd4', '2013-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd4', '2014-01-31 22:04:15' from dual
        union all
        select 'd4', '2015-01-31 22:04:15' from dual)
 where id in ('d3', 'd4')
 group by id;
```

If there are more columns add those also into your group by fields.